# Filter quotes by owner division SOQL

Tags: soql, query, jsforce

I am using JsForce to query my orgs salesforce data. I am trying to select all quotes that belong to salespeople from my division. I am very new to SOQL and SalesForce so the best I have come up with is:

```
SELECT GrandTotal FROM Quote WHERE Owner.Division='Europe'
```

However this errors with "Did not understand relationship" even though I can see in the salesforce ui that the owner field of a quote has a division attribute. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_quote.htm) for Quote object details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this query doesn't work is because for Quote, the OwnerId field is polymorphic to both `User` and `Group`

So, you need to use a polymorphic query:

```
SELECT GrandTotal FROM Quote WHERE Owner.Type = 'User' AND Owner.Division='Europe'
```

[Polymorphic query reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys)

[image]